# Symfony 1.4 how to link_to or url_for an admin generated module?

Tags: php, symfony-1.4

So faw I have been using `url_for()` to link to module, its important to get the `/frontend_dev.php` in my links. However, this function wont find admin generated modules. How to dodge it, so that I get backend_dev.php prefix?

Comment: What have you tried? And by the way, give us feedback on your others questions: solved, not-solved, then why, etc ..

Comment: like I said, I tried the usual url_for() and link_to() functions, and symfony drops an error: not found. "The route "%s" does not exist"

Comment: Then show us the route you tried and also your routing.yml.

Comment: I didnt touch it. I must edit it to get correct route?

Comment: Show us how do you use link_for or url_for so that it generate this error....

Comment: Some good staring points: [symfony blog post](http://symfony.com/blog/cross-application-links), [SO #1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6368043/symfony-multiple-application-interaction), [SO #2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6368043/symfony-multiple-application-interaction), [SO #3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10136416/symfony-1-4-cross-application-link-fail)

Comment: Sadly I couldnt understood it, I did a helper for this.